# How to ignore the exception and continue the script run

Tags: perl

i am running a Vmware script where it goes half way through and then fails with below error and exits:

`Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at test.pl line 49`.

This is running on a vCetner inventory which has ~4000 VMs. So I want the script to ignore such erros and continue running until it finishes. At the moment the script exits withouht any ouput after above error.

here is my code which gives me the above error. I am pasting only few lines where the error arises from:

```
foreach my $vm_mo_ref ( @{ $host_view->vm } )
{
        print $vm_mo_ref."\n";
}
```

This is what I did to ignore the error:

```
foreach my $vm_mo_ref ( @{ $host_view->vm } )
{
    if (defined $vm_mo_ref)
    {   
            print $vm_mo_ref."\n";
    }
}
```

and

```
foreach my $vm_mo_ref ( @{ $host_view->vm } )
{
    if (exists $vm_mo_ref)
    {   
            print $vm_mo_ref."\n";
    }
}
```

and

```
foreach my $vm_mo_ref ( @{ $host_view->vm } )
{
    if ($vm_mo_ref)
    {   
            print $vm_mo_ref."\n";
    }
}
```

and

```
foreach my $vm_mo_ref ( @{ $host_view->vm } )
{
    if (ref($vm_mo_ref) eq "ARRAY")
    {   
            print $vm_mo_ref."\n";
    }
}
```

and

```
foreach my $vm_mo_ref ( @{ $host_view->vm } )
{
    if (ref($vm_mo_ref) eq "ManagedObjectReference")
    {   
            print $vm_mo_ref."\n";
    }
}
```

However, none of above five approaches with "if" condition are working and my script still fails/exits with aforementioned error.

BTW, `ManagedObjectReference` is Vmware specific reference.

Could you help me get around this error and continue with the rest of the script.
Thanks.

Comment: The thing you're using as an array ref is `$host_view->vm`. That's the thing you need to check _before_ the loop.

Comment: Awesome. please put your response in answers section so that i can accept it. Many thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Perhaps you should check the reason the value is undefined. That's what warnings are for, you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
foreach my $vm_mo_ref ( @{ $host_view->vm || [] } )
```

Nothing you change in the loop will have any effect because your code throws an exception before it even enters the loop.

Comment: Or, even better, use the defined-or `//` instead of the logical or `||`. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's `@{ }` throwing the error, so your check comes way too late. This is how you'd do the check early enough:

```
if (my $vm = $host_view->vm)
{
    foreach my $vm_mo_ref (@$vm)
    {
        print $vm_mo_ref."\n";
    }
}
```

The alternative is to create an array on demand. It's a bit wasteful, but it makes for clear code.

```
foreach my $vm_mo_ref (@{ $host_view->vm // [] })
{
    print $vm_mo_ref."\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I liked the 1st option that you mentioned.